# Simple WQL query issue

Tags: sccm, wql

The full query:

```
select 
  SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name,
  SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Model,
  SMS_R_System.OperatingSystemNameandVersion,
  SMS_R_System.Build,
  SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName

from 
  SMS_R_System
    inner join SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM on SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.ResourceID = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
    INNER JOIN SMS_UserMachineRelationship ON SMS_UserMachineRelationship.ResourceId = SMS_R_System.ResourceId
    INNER JOIN SMS_R_User ON SMS_UserMachineRelationship.UniqueUserName = SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName

WHERE 
  SMS_UserMachineRelationship.Types = 1
  SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName LIKE "%,%"

order by 
  SMS_G_System_COMPUTER_SYSTEM.Name
```

The issue I am here to discuss and need assistance with is jut this line:

```
SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName LIKE "%,%"
```

No matter what I try here after the LIKE operator, it is just always a syntax error.  Have no idea what is wrong with it, it matches all the examples online, and previous queries I have written.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you write *a syntax error*, the very next thing that follows should be the **complete, exact error message**. It contains useful information, and it's on the screen right in front of you. We can't see that screen from here. You're asking us to help you solve your problem, and it's in your best interest to make it as easy as possible for us to do so by providing the details  you already have available.

Comment: Hey Ken, in SCCM it lierally just says "there was a syntax error in your script, would you like to save anyway?".   That's it.   I think I have made an error anyway, I am about to update my question :D

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. You can't change the code after people have written answers dependent on that code. We don't aim at moving targets here. If you now have a separate problem, ask a new question about that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error. You're missing an `AND` between the two conditions in your `WHERE` clause. This is standard SQL syntax, so it's nothing special related to WQL.

It should be

```
WHERE 
  SMS_UserMachineRelationship.Types = 1 AND
  SMS_R_User.UniqueUserName LIKE "%,%"
```

Comment: Yep!  This was exactly the issue with my original question.  I tried this right after i posted the question and it removed the syntax error immediately.   I then updated the question but I will post it as a new question.   Thanks.